# Analyze Coil - Iron system Problem

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I'm working on a coil - iron system analyze project

A problem that I faced with is effect of movements of the iron on the coil current & force

I want to analyze force of the coil on iron block in a situation that Coil is pulling the iron block and iron block is moving to coil center

so we know the coil did some work and converted its magnetic energy to kinetic energy of the iron block.
I want to know how this work energy is calculated and decreases the coil energy.

I know different positions of iron block changes inductance of the coil

the coil is acting in this equation : `V = L * di/dt` so the only thing that comes to my mind is the change of inductance during iron block movement can handle that work and makes a change to coil's energy. is it right ? or there is other equations to play this rule?

Also I want to know how this equation describes generation of electricity in a coil with moving an iron block around it. I'm a bit confused with it

Comment: Is your coil powered with an AC or DC current?

Comment: Its DC powered.